# Did Charles Babbage lay out his log table like this?

Tags: logarithm, charles-babbage

We read that [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) was [interested in building a machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) to tabulate polynomial functions. This came from [writing a book of log tables](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-babbage-s-tables-of-logarithms).

[Here we see an example](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-log-table) of how to use a log table:
[image]

My question is: **Did Charles Babbage lay out his log table (from his book) like this?**

Comment: What are you asking?  How Babbage laid out his tables, or how many digits of precision, or...?

Comment: See C.Babbage, [Table of the Logarithms of the Natural Numbers from 1 to 108000](https://books.google.it/books?id=qD5wRgrz20kC&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No.

There is a wonderful mathematical simplicity to the way that [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) lays out his log tables.

On the first couple of pages he lays it out like this:

[image]

Then when he gets to the thousands, he lays it out like this:

[image]